# Plot igraph tree objects with ggtree

Tags: r, igraph

Generating trees as a subclass of graphs with the [igraph package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=igraph) is the de-facto standard in `R`.

The package [ggtree](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ggtree.html) is very versatile in tree visualization. It [seems](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.1/bioc/vignettes/ggtree/inst/doc/ggtree.html) some plotting functionalities go beyond the capabilties of [igraph](http://cran.r-project.org/package=igraph).

This leads to the question:

Is there a way to use a valid tree graph object generated by [igraph](http://cran.r-project.org/package=igraph) package (i.e. example below) as input for a visualization with `ggtree`?

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.tree(20, 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a good idea.

ggtree is designed for phylogenetic analysis. Some of the functionalities may not be applied to other objects like igraph directly. To make the support more smoothly is to convert the igraph object as a phylo object. So that after conversion, ggtree can be used to visualize it and all functionalities are supported.

The issue for conversion is that igraph allow singleton as in the example posted while phylo don't allow since it's meaningless in evolution.

I will consider to develop a conversion function in future version.

#### reference

**G Yu**, DK Smith, H Zhu, Y Guan, TTY Lam<sup>*</sup>. [ggtree: an R package for visualization and annotation of phylogenetic trees with their covariates and other associated data](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.12628/abstract). ***Methods in Ecology and Evolution***. [`doi:10.1111/2041-210X.12628`](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/2041-210X.12628).

Comment: I would just like to note that singleton nodes are meaningful in mutation trees. I am trying to use ggtree with mutation trees, but I am having difficulties with singleton nodes. Are there any plans to expand ggtree to be applicable to mutation trees?